# Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined in angular when using @viewchild

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ecmascript-6, single-page-application

In my code, i have a div named #map that will displayed after a condition from a for loop.

```
<div *ngFor="let message of fullMessagesArr">
 <div *ngIf="message.replyMap">
   <div #gmap style="width:100px;height:400px"></div>
 </div>
</div>
```

My .ts file given below with `initMap` function.

```
@ViewChild('gmap') gmapElement: ElementRef;
map: google.maps.Map;

  initGMap = () => {
    const mapProp = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(6.9404, 79.8464),
      zoom: 15,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.satellite
    };
    this.map = new google.maps.Map(this.gmapElement.nativeElement, mapProp);
  }
```

`initGMap` function is getting called inside `sendMessage` function.

Comment: Where is `fullMessagesArr` set? Either it's not set, or it's empty, or none of the messages get the `replyMap` property set

Comment: no, it is not empty, i put items to it from a API call and it is not empty, i checked that

Comment: can you show us the code for that?

Comment: error is not in the array, problem occurs when i use @viewchild and try to load the map with initGMap function

Comment: It can be a synchronisation problem. If you call initGMap before fullMessagesArr has been assigned a value, it can lead to these problems. What is printed in the console can be misleading btw

Comment: Another issue with your code is that you have `#gmap` inside an `ngFor`, so you can have multiple gmaps, but ViewChild should just reference one object.

Comment: In my code, I have a *ngIf inside the for loop, it only display when the relevant item appeared from the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seem like you are trying to access the element when it not visible to DOM yet so what you can do is run setTimeOut or use ngAfterContentInit life cycle hook to wait for the DOM to be render

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy, AfterContentInit {

    public ngAfterContentInit(): void {
       const mapProp = {
           center: new google.maps.LatLng(6.9404, 79.8464),
           zoom: 15,
           mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.satellite
       };
       this.map = new google.maps.Map(this.gmapElement.nativeElement, mapProp);
    }
}
```

or use setTimeOut

```
initGMap = () => {
    const mapProp = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(6.9404, 79.8464),
      zoom: 15,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.satellite
    };
    setTimeout(() => {
         this.map = new google.maps.Map(this.gmapElement.nativeElement, mapProp);
    }, 3000);
  }
```